# modify xml file python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml file that looks like this

filename: abc.nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>aa-bb-cc</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>first last</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Google DialogFlow proto classes library</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0">
        <dependency id="Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2" version="3.1.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Google.Protobuf" version="3.15.6" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Grpc.Core" version="2.36.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Grpc.Core.Api" version="2.36.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Grpc.Net.Client" version="2.36.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I would like to add below line if already not present in metadata field,

"< repository url="https://github.com/test/test-repo" type="get" />"

Here is the code i found

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse(f'abc.nuspec').getroot()
path = root.find("metadata")
myattributes = {"url": "https://github.com/test/test-repo", "type": "get"}
new = ET.SubElement(path, 'repository', attrib=myattributes)
print(ET.tostring(root, short_empty_elements=False).decode())
```

but the above code didnt work. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: There are many similar questions. The document declares a default namespace (`http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd`) that you need to take into account. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check, if the repository tag is inside the metadata tag list, if not create a SubElement(). And don’t forget to register your namespace:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("abc.nuspec")
root = tree.getroot()

namespaces = {node[0]: node[1] for event, node in ET.iterparse("abc.nuspec", events=['start-ns'])}
print("My Namespaces:", namespaces,'\n')
for ns in namespaces:
    ET.register_namespace(ns, namespaces[ns])
    

for meta in root.findall("metadata", namespaces):
    if meta.findall("repository", namespaces):
        pass
    else:
        rep = ET.SubElement(meta, "repository")
        rep.set("url", "https://github.com/test/test-repo")
        rep.set("type", "get" )
        
ET.dump(root)

tree1 = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree1, space= '  ')
tree1.write('abc_new.nuspec', encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True)
```